# Doubts about concurrency in injected services in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, async-await, concurrency

I have a service injected into the **ASP.NET** dotnet framework **service container**. I **inject this service as a Singleton**, and its function is to maintain several data structures (**Dictionay**, **List**, **Queue**) in memory.

The service is perfectly accessible from the *controllers*, and my doubts are due to the lack of knowledge of the internal workings of ASP.NET.

My questions are:

- Should I worry about creating the **Singleton** (*thread safe*) or does the container take care of it?
- Are accesses to service methods *enqueued in a single thread*?, or can they be *called concurrently*? I ask to know if I have to use **Concurrent Collections** instead of the **Generic** ones.
- Would it be convenient to make the methods *asynchronous*?

I accept any suggestion, and examples.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have too many questions and should boil it down to a single question. That said, the container will guarantee singleton registration. You don't have to. You should ALWAYS assume that singletons will be accessed
 concurrently and you _MUST_ guarantee thread safety yourself. And finally, there is rarely a reason to not have apis being async/await.

Comment: ASP.NET controllers are scoped per request. It's usually okay for dependencies to also be generated per scope. But there is no substitute for knowing whether individual classes can support concurrency or should. Any answer to that question that's right in one case is likely wrong in another.

Comment: Simple but clear answers. Both.
I see that I have to redo the methods in asynchronous mode, and rewrite the data structures in concurrent mode